# How to get an impulse response of a MIMO system?

Tags: matlab, impulse-response, filtering, adaptive-filters, lms

So I have data vectors from a MIMO system and I wish to see the impulse response
Any idea how I can proceed with this?

Comment: What’s the “data”?

Comment: The whole system should be characterised by four impulse responses (one for each speaker-microphone pair). Is this what you are after, or you’d like some other kind of estimate? Additionally, like @Jdip mentioned, what is the “data” you refer to?

Comment: Was this an actual MIMO measurement? As in, were the signals played by the 2 speakers at the same time? In that case, to get individual impulse responses, the excitation signals must be un-correlated with each other, and span as much of the bandwidth that you’re interested in as possible. A sine wave is clearly not an excitation signal you can work with.

Comment: "The speaker and microphone data seem..."  This is insufficient.  Please _edit your question_ to say how the data was collected, whether it was collected with the intent of finding the "system" transfer function, if you have _any_ a-priori knowledge of what was supposed to be sent and received, what the rough setup is (i.e., speakers and microphones in an anechoic chamber, in a room, in a corn field, etc., right next to each other, miles away, etc., the electronic connection to the speakers and microphones, how well the four channels are synchronized, etc.)

Comment: Have you actually tried implementing the LMS (or the Normalised LMS) algorithm for the data you have? You could definitely try both and see which one gives the best results. I don’t think that we’ll be able to provide more insight into which *should* be the best algorithm as we don’t have much information about the problem anyway (for example, an RLS or even an FxLMS might be more appropriate here, but unless we know more we can’t help more).

Comment: I ain't in favor of closing this question.  It might need some refining.

Comment: Being that you have simultaneously excited ***both*** speakers and taken measurements, makes this more difficult.  If you had driven one speaker (leaving the other silent) taking measurements in both microphones and repeated the same measurement driving the other speaker, it would be simple to extract the system response.  There may be a way to do this with LMS or NLMS, as long as the impulse response is shorter than half of your signal width.  But it's funky.